# Why is the JButton not showing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have tried to make a JButton and to add it to the JFrame but it doesn't appear. No errors. I am more confused by the fact that I can add the point object but not the JButtton. So any help on how to fix it would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaGraphics extends JFrame {

    JavaGraphics() throws HeadlessException {
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new DrawArea());
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaGraphics();
    }
}

class DrawArea extends JPanel {
    Point A = null;
    Point B = null;
    JButton button;
    public DrawArea() {
        A = new Point(100, 200);
        B = new Point(200, 300);
        button = new JButton("Text");
        button.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);

    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y);
        g.drawString("A", A.x, A.y);
        g.drawString("B", B.x, B.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not be extending JFrame.  It is bad technique.  Just use an instance.  Please check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572080/cant-add-graphics-into-jpanel-in-java/59572396#59572396) on doing graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually add it to anything.

```
  public DrawArea() {
        A = new Point(100, 200);
        B = new Point(200, 300);
        button = new JButton("Text");
        button.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);

        this.add(button); // add this line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the JButton to the constructor of class DrawArea:

```
 public DrawArea() {
        A = new Point(100, 200);
        B = new Point(200, 300);
        button = new JButton("Text");
        button.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);

        add(button);
    }
```