# How to change graphic color

Tags: java

So I'm trying to change the color that these rectangles will be when I draw them on the canvas but they always come out grey even though I set the color for the graphics. Here's my code:

```
public static void rectTransition(int[] array, int smallerNumberIndex) throws InterruptedException
{
    for(int x = 0;x<10;x++)
    {
        if(smallerNumberIndex%2==0)
        {
            canvas.getGraphics().setColor(new Color(000000));
            canvas.getGraphics().clearRect(((smallerNumberIndex*10)+9)-x, 600, 1, -array[smallerNumberIndex]*10);
            canvas.getGraphics().clearRect(((smallerNumberIndex*10)-1)-x, 600, 1, -array[smallerNumberIndex]*10);
            canvas.getGraphics().drawRect(((smallerNumberIndex*10)-1)-x, 600, 1, -array[smallerNumberIndex]*10);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.getGraphics().setColor(new Color(20, 217, 72));
            canvas.getGraphics().clearRect(((smallerNumberIndex*10)+9)-x, 600, 1, -array[smallerNumberIndex]*10);
            canvas.getGraphics().clearRect(((smallerNumberIndex*10)-1)-x, 600, 1, -array[smallerNumberIndex]*10);
            canvas.getGraphics().drawRect(((smallerNumberIndex*10)-1)-x, 600, 1, -array[smallerNumberIndex]*10);
        }
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling fillRect instead of drawRect? It might just be that you can't see the color. Are you sure you're drawing the rectangle within the bounds of the application? Can't really help until I see how this is being called.

Comment: That is not how you should be painting.  Don't use `Canvas`.  Use `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(g)`  Check this out for an example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572080/cant-add-graphics-into-jpanel-in-java/59572396#59572396